# Why does bind not work with pass by reference?

Tags: c++, stdbind

I find pass by reference tends not to work when using std::bind. Here's an example.

```
int test;

void inc(int &i)
{
    i++;
}

int main() {
    test = 0;
    auto i = bind(inc, test);
    i();
    cout<<test<<endl; // Outputs 0, should be 1
    inc(test);
    cout<<test<<endl; // Outputs 1
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't the variable incrementing when called via the function created with std bind?

Comment: Use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to pass a reference to std::bind!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::bind` copies the argument provided, then it passes the copy to your function. In order to pass a reference to `bind` you need to use `std::ref`:`auto i = bind(inc, std::ref(test));`