# How can I std::bind a user-provided function to a member variable of type std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, std-function, stdbind

I have a class with a member variable `std::function customCallback`, and I need to let the user customize its behavior. `customCallback` should take as input a `const std::array<int, N>&` and a `int`, and return a `std::array<int, N>` (where `N` is a template parameter).

I am currently using `std::bind` to achieve this, but I can't understand why the compilation fails. What am I missing?

Since the original code involves inheritance and templates, I am including inheritance and templates in my minimal reproducible example ([live code here](https://ideone.com/wWElH8)) as well.

The user should be able to use both the constructor OR a member function to set the custom behavior.

`base.h`:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <functional>

template <std::size_t N>
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual std::array<int, N> CustomBehavior(const std::array<int, N>& user_array, int user_number) = 0;    
protected:
    std::array<int, N> my_array = {0, 0};
};
```

`derived.h`:

```cpp
#include <base.h>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<N> {
public:
    DerivedClass() = default;

    DerivedClass(std::function<std::array<int, N>(const std::array<int, N>&, int)> custom_f)
        : customCallback(std::bind(custom_f, std::ref(std::placeholders::_1), std::placeholders::_2)) {}

    void SetCustomBehavior(std::function<std::array<int, N>(const std::array<int>&, int)> custom_f) {
        customCallback = std::bind(custom_f, std::ref(std::placeholders::_1), std::placeholders::_2);
    }

    std::array<int, N> CustomBehavior(const std::array<int, N>& user_array, int user_number) override {
        if (customCallback)
            this->my_array = customCallback(user_array, user_number);
        return this->my_array;
    }

private:
    std::function<std::array<int, N>(const std::array<int, N>&, int)> customCallback;
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <derived.h>
#include <cassert>

static constexpr std::size_t MySize = 2;

std::array<int, MySize> my_behavior(const std::array<int, MySize>& input_array, int a) {
    return {a * input_array[0], a * input_array[1]};
}

int main() {

    std::array<int, MySize> my_array = {1, 1};

    // Default constructor (COMPILES)
    DerivedClass<MySize> foo_1; // OK
    std::array<int, MySize> bar_1 = foo_1.CustomBehavior(my_array, 2);
    assert(bar_1[0] == 0 && bar_1[1] == 0);

    // Custom constructor (ERROR)
    DerivedClass<MySize> foo_2(my_behavior); // COMPILATION ERROR
    std::array<int, MySize> bar_2 = foo_2.CustomBehavior(my_array, 2);
    assert(bar_2[0] == 2 && bar_2[1] == 2);

    // Custom behavior set later on (ERROR)
    DerivedClass<MySize> foo_3;  // OK
    foo_3.SetCustomBehavior(my_behavior); // COMPILATION ERROR
    std::array<int, MySize> bar_3 = foo_3.CustomBehavior(my_array, 2);
    assert(bar_3[0] == 2 && bar_3[1] == 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not including the whole compilation error since it's fairly long, but it can be seen [live code here](https://ideone.com/wWElH8).

Comment: Why do you think you need `bind` when the types are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, the first error you are getting is an error on `std::array<int>` in `Derived::SetCustomBehavior()`:

> error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

You also have an error on `std::ref(std::placeholders::_1)`, it should be just `std::placeholders::_1`.

Fixing those two mistakes, the code then compiles and runs (using corrected asserts):

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/FxuJOE)

That being said, you don't actually need `std::bind()` at all in this situation. Your `custom_f` parameter is the same type as your `customCallback` member, so simply assign `custom_f` as-is to `customCallback`.

And do yourself a favor - create type aliases for your `std::function` and `std::array` types to make your code more readable.

Try this:

base.h

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
using intArray = std::array<int, N>;

template<std::size_t N>
using callbackType = 
std::function<intArray<N>(const intArray<N>&, int)>;

template <std::size_t N>
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual intArray<N> CustomBehavior(const intArray<N>& user_array, int user_number) = 0;
protected:
    intArray<N> my_array = {0, 0};
};
```

derived.h:

```cpp
#include "base.h"

template <std::size_t N>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<N> {
public:
    DerivedClass() = default;

    DerivedClass(callbackType<N> custom_f)
        : customCallback(std::move(custom_f))
    {}

    void SetCustomBehavior(callbackType<N> custom_f) {
        customCallback = std::move(custom_f);
    }

    intArray<N> CustomBehavior(const intArray<N>& user_array, int user_number) override {
        if (customCallback)
            this->my_array = customCallback(user_array, user_number);
        return this->my_array;
    }

private:
    callbackType<N> customCallback;
};
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "derived.h" 
#include <cassert>

static constexpr std::size_t MySize = 2;
using myIntArray = intArray<MySize>;

myIntArray my_behavior(const myIntArray& input_array, int a) {
    return {a * input_array[0], a * input_array[1]};
}

int main() {
    myIntArray my_array = {1, 1};

    // Default constructor
    DerivedClass<MySize> foo_1;

    myIntArray bar_1 = foo_1.CustomBehavior(my_array, 2);
    assert(bar_1[0] == 0 && bar_1[1] == 0);

    // Custom constructor
    DerivedClass<MySize> foo_2(my_behavior);
    myIntArray bar_2 = foo_2.CustomBehavior(my_array, 2);
    assert(bar_2[0] == 2 && bar_2[1] == 2);

    // Custom behavior set later on
    DerivedClass<MySize> foo_3;
    foo_3.SetCustomBehavior(my_behavior);
    myIntArray bar_3 = foo_3.CustomBehavior(my_array, 2);
    assert(bar_3[0] == 2 && bar_3[1] == 2);

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ianxtd)

Comment: The first assert will fail since `std::function` is empty at first.

Comment: @康桓瑋 fixed, thanks

Comment: Thank you! I have been struggling with this for an hour and had no idea you could directly assign functions like that.
I am indeed using aliases in the original code, for my mental sanity. I was just trying to be more explicit here.

Comment: @康桓瑋 thank you for pointing that out, I wash in a rush. I fixed it in the original question as well.

Comment: On a side note, do you know why the version using `std::bind` wouldn't work? I get that it's unnecessarily complex, but how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: @giacomo-b I updated my answer to address that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank, I will try that right away. The reason I was using `std::ref` is that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811096/5617293) mentions that using `std::bind` copies the arguments if `std::ref` is not used.